# Authenticating user from another model in Django?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to use `GalaxyUser` model to authenticate in Django:

```
class GalaxyUser(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=765)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    external = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    purged = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True)
    form_values_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    disk_usage = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=16, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'galaxy_user'
```

I have included this line in `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'fileupload.GalaxyUser'
```

My login function is:

```
def login_backend(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/overview/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login_backend/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('login_backend.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However the authentication is not working. Am I doing everything, right?

Comment: One thing I notice is that you are not deriving GalaxyUser from AbstractBaseUser.  Could you give us more info about what is failing with authentication? What error messages or behavior are you seeing?  Are you on Django 1.5?

Comment: The function is still authenticating from the DJango auth_user table. The username and password from GalaxyUser is not working.

Comment: Actually I am on Django 1.4.1 so this feature seems to be not available. How can I do this in Django 1.4.1?

Comment: I'd recommend exploring two options. 1) Modify the GalaxyUser model so it has a foreign key to the User model, and let the User model store username/email/password. If you just want to use the built in django auth and store some extra data about users, a foreign key is your best bet.  2)  If you really want to use the GalaxyUser model as-is, you could create your own authentication backend.  Tell us a little more about why django's built in authentication is not what you want and what you are trying to accomplish and hopefully someone can make a good recommendation about how to proceed.